# Redirect From void method in Basecontroller in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I am a new bee to asp.Net MVC. I have a scenario where, if a custom exception occur inside the application then i need to redirect to login page.
The catch block will look like..

```
catch (Exception ex){                
                WriteLog(ex, TalxCategories.Business);
            }

public virtual void WriteLog(Exception ex, Category category){
                CsaWebLogger.Current.WriteError(ex, category);
            }
```

The issue i face is like 
I need to redirect from WriteLog method.since method is void i cannot use 
return redirect..
Another aproach which i tried is like..

```
var context = new RequestContext(
    new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current), 
    new RouteData());
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context);
var url = urlHelper.Action("Index", new { OtherParm = "other value" });
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url);
```

This aproach also didnt work for me.Please help me to redirect from the WriteLog method to Login action.

Comment: Can you explain why you need this? It looks like you are writing to a log, and it seems a bit strange that an error in the logging mechanism should redirect the user to a login page. Maybe there is a better way to solve the actual problem you are facing.

Comment: My  application is using a token based authentication.This token will be alive for a fixed time interval .Since i am handling exception in my home controller try catch, execution will not hit onexception method in base controller.so i plan to redirect from writelog method in basecontroller which is called from catch.Whenever the token gets expired, the application will get tokenexpired exception on any request.My requirement is to redirect to login page at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Add [HandleError] to your controller or in filterconfig.cs as filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute()) if not present

Create custom filter for exception handling 
Follow the below steps

1.Create a class which inherits from FilterAttribute and IExceptionFilter interface
And call WriteLog() as shown

```
public class CustomExceptionHandler : FilterAttribute ,IExceptionFilter
{
public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        WriteLog(filterContext.Exception, TalxCategories.Business);
    }
}
```

1.Decorate your controller [CustomExceptionHandler] or register in FilterConfig as filters.Add(new CustomExceptionHandler());
Thats it.
You are achieving 2 things. Logging and redirecting to custom page